# Having trouble selecting properties with XSLT

Tags: xslt

I need to select Property1, and SubProperty2 and strip out any other properties.  I need to make this future proof so that any new properties added to the xml won't break validation.  iow's new fields have to be stripped by default.

```
<Root>
    <Property1/>
    <Property2/>
    <Thing>
        <SubProperty1/>
        <SubProperty2/>
    </Thing>
    <VariousProperties/>
</Root>
```

so in my xslt I did this:

```
  <xsl:template match="Property1">
     <Property1>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </Property1>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/Thing">
    <SubProperty1>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="SubProperty1" />
    </SubProperty1>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*" />
```

The last line should strip anything I haven't defined to be selected.

This works to select my property1 but it always selects an empty node for SubProperty.  The match on * seems to strip out the deeper object before my match on them can work.
I removed the match on * and it select my SubProperty with a value.  So,  how can I select the sub properties and still strip everything away that I am not using.

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: Nevermind... I figured out how to do what I needed...

Answer (score 0):

**There are two problems**:

```
<xsl:template match="*"/>
```

This ignores any element for which there isn't an overriding, more specific template.

Because there isn't a specific template for the top element `Root` it is ignored together with all of its subtree -- which is the complete document -- no output at all is produced.

**The second problem is here**:

```
<xsl:template match="/Thing">
```

This template matches the top element named `Thing`.

However in the provided document the top element is named `Root`. Therefore the above template doesn't match any node from the provided XML document and is never selected for execution. As the code inside its body is supposed to generate `SubProperty1`, no such output is generated.

**Solution**:

**Change**

```
<xsl:template match="*"/>
```

**to**:

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

**And change**

```
<xsl:template match="/Thing">
```

**to**

```
<xsl:template match="Thing">
```

**The whole transformation becomes**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

      <xsl:template match="Property1">
         <Property1>
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
         </Property1>
      </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="Thing">
        <SubProperty1>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="SubProperty1" />
        </SubProperty1>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**And when applied on the following XML document** (as the provided is severely malformed it had to be fixed):

```
<Root>
    <Property1/>
    <Property2/>
    <Thing>
        <SubProperty1/>
        <SubProperty2/>
    </Thing>
    <VariousProperties/>
</Root>
```

**the result now is what is wanted**:

```
<Property1/>
<SubProperty1/>
```